# Undefined method phpseclib\Crypt\RSA::loadKey()

Tags: php

I'm trying to use phplibsec to upload files in SFTP using private key authentication.

I got the following error when trying the sample provided with phplibsec:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method phpseclib\Crypt\RSA::loadKey()
```

It looks like the `loadKey` function is nowhere to be found in phplibsec..

it works fine when authentication with a logon password tough.

I must be missing something.. some php library that should be installed ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `load()` method:

```
$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->load($keystr);
```

From what I can tell it was [renamed in this commit](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/ec3fe7277b8b1c4250c939f39783840ca12c1a19?diff=unified).